# Show Custom Category Attribute in Specific Categories. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, attributes, custom-attributes

I've created a custom attribute using

> Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    )
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'set_commission',
            [
                'type'         => 'varchar',
                'label'        => 'Set Commission',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'sort_order'   => 100,
                'source'       => '',
                'global'       => 1,
                'visible'      => true,
                'required'     => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default'      => null,
                'group'        => '',
                'backend'      => ''
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

n also this attribute in category by using

> view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="set_commission">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">333</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Set Commission</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

now the issue is I want to show the above attribute in only **Level 2 categories** is there is any way to set that? Thanks